# Algorithm: Finding pattern between n and i?

Tags: algorithm, iteration, logarithm

I have the following simple algorithm:

```
int i = 2;
int n = {Domain is all integers >= 2}

while (I < N)
I = I * I;
execute(command);
end-while
```

I understand how many time the command with execute(ex. `n=16` will execute `3` times, `n=256`, `4` times, etc.)
I would like to know the best way to express the number of executes in terms of N.

Comment: Define criteria for "best way". How would you measure it? Or compare. Or do you just want the formula?

Comment: Look up "logarithm". Then look up "logarithm" again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to know simple concept of [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

But it is not just a simple one level logarithm, a simple logarithm could solve issue like this :

> 2<sup>k</sup> = n ==> log<sub>2</sub>(n) = k

but you have :

> 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> = n ==> log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n))
>   = k

so your answer is : **log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n))**

**Proof of your iteration is 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>:**

for first iteration you have **2<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup> = 4** suppose for k'th iteration you have  **2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>** now for k+1 iteration you have:

**2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> * 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup></sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>k+1</sup></sup>** and it is proven by induction :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the formula, then it's simple. You need to count how many iterations there will be... Just analyze how `I` will grow in each iteration.

1. `I` = `i^2` = `i^(2^1)`
2. `I` = `i^2^2` = `i^(2^2)`
3. `I` = `i^2^2^2` = `i^(2^3)`
4. `I` = `i^2^2^2^2` =  `i^(2^4)`

etc. `k-th` is `i^(2^k)`

Now you need to get `k` from `I`.

`log i (I)` = `log i (i^(2^k))` => `(2^k)`

`log 2 (2^k)` => `k`

`k` = `log i (log 2 (I))`

Now, you can apply that `I` is always lower than `N`, thus number of iterations is bound by `log i (log 2 (N))`. The exact number needs to be adjusted to your bounduary conditions. You do no initialize `I` nowhere, so there is an assumption that `I=i` before 1st iteration. Also `I <= N` and `I < N` will make a difference on exact powers.

Answer (score -1):

There is no formula for this calculation as per my knowledge. Since the number of executions duplicates with a set of number. I have done a simulation on this upto 2 power 20 numbers. Below is the python code

```
1.for n= 2 Count is  0
2.for n= 4 Count is  1
3.for n= 8 Count is  2
4.for n= 16 Count is  2
5.for n= 32 Count is  3
6.for n= 64 Count is  3
7.for n= 128 Count is  3
8.for n= 256 Count is  3
9.for n= 512 Count is  4
10.for n= 1024 Count is  4
11.for n= 2048 Count is  4
12.for n= 4096 Count is  4
13.for n= 8192 Count is  4
14.for n= 16384 Count is  4
15.for n= 32768 Count is  4
16.for n= 65536 Count is  4
17.for n= 131072 Count is  5
18.for n= 262144 Count is  5
19.for n= 524288 Count is  5
```

Code

```
__author__ = 'Abhilash'
import math
i = 2;
n = 2048
k=[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096, 8192 , 16384 , 32768 , 65536 , 131072 , 262144 , 524288 ]
for b in range(0,20):
    print int(math.pow(2,b)),",",
x=0
for b in range(0,len(k)):
    n=k[b]
    x=0
    i=2
    while i < n:
        i=i*i
        x=x+1
    print "for n=",n,"
```

Comment: Could you clarify?  when n=3 the command executes once, (first iteration i = 2, second iteration i = 4, third i = 16), so if n=3.. 2(3^2) = 18 and 3^2 * 3^2 = 81... am i missing something?